# How to pass data to component that is already declared in default.vue and call from other pages?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Currently I have a component called **Alert** this contains the bootstrap alert element.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-alert :show="alertState" dismissible :variant="variant">
      {{message}}
    </b-alert>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      message: { type: String },
      variant: { type: String }, 
      state: { type: String, default: 'hidden' }
    }, 
    computed: {
      alertState() {
        return this.state == 'show' ? true : false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

and I'm calling the component in **layouts/default.vue**

```
<template>
 <div>
    <Alert state="show" variant="success" message="Hello World"/>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import Alert from '~/components/UI/Alert';
export default {
  components: {
    Alert
  }
}
</script>
```

from my other pages **users/new.vue** I have axios POST request and in my axios response if success or not, how can I call the component that is already declared in **default.vue** and pass a data like message, variant(success, danger)?

Current code:

```
axios.post(url, { name: 'Hello' })
  .then(function (response) {
          console.log(`success ${response}`);
          // show success with message in Alert component
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(`failed ${error}`);
          // show failed with message in Alert component
        });
```

Comment: It depends on the relation between `default.vue` and `new.vue`, if they're parent/child you should dispatch events from the child and then pass props from the parent. If the relationship is more complex I recommend that you use something like `vuex` https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to share data between your `<page>.vue` and your `<layout>.vue` is to use the Vuex Store. You can use it to have a global Alert state.

see doc: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store

---

## 1/ Create store

```
// your-project/store/index.js

export const state = () => ({
  alert: null
});

export const mutations = {
  SET_ALERT (state, value) {
    console.log('SET_ALERT', value);
    state.alert = value;
  }
};
```

## 2/ Feed store on success/error

```
// your-project/pages/<page>.vue

asyncData ({ store }) {

  axios.post(url, { name: 'Hello' })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(`success ${response}`);
      // show success with message in Alert component
      store.commit('SET_ALERT', { message: "POST done!", variant: "success" });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(`failed ${error}`);
      // show failed with message in Alert component
      store.commit('SET_ALERT', { message: "Error on POST!", variant: "error" });
    });

  // ...
}
```

## 3/ Read store from layout

```
// your-project/layout/default.vue

<template>
 <div>
    <Alert state="show" :variant="$store.state.alert.variant" :message="$store.state.alert.message"/>
 </div>
</template>

//...
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, I was able to show the alert when I commit the SET_ALERT in index.vue. But when I trigger it in other page like new.vue or _id.vue I'm getting an error failed TypeError: Cannot read property '$store' of undefined. 

BTW my vue x file is under store/index.js

Comment: I'm triggering the commit from my new.vue like this: 

this.$store.commit('SET_ALERT', { variant: 'success', message: 'Insider details has been updated'});

Comment: Okay I know already I manually import it on the page I need it. 
import { store } from '~/store/index'; 

but is it the correct way to do it? Thanks Nicolas

Comment: `$store` is for  `<template>` or `store` on `<script>` +  `asyncData ({ store }) { ... }` or `this.$store` on  `<script>` + `methods: { ... }`. But I never used  `import` to call my store. see example: https://github.com/NicoPennec/nuxt-weather/blob/master/pages/weather/_citycode.vue#L30